# ASP.NET MVC: How to display a detail from one-to-many related model in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So basically I have a Post model, which is associated with the user that created it:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

And the ApplicationUser has posts:

```
public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

So now on the Posts index view page, I just want to show the Email of the ApplicationUser who wrote the post. So the following doesn't work (it just shows blank on the page):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationUser.Email)
```

What's the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm pretty sure that no one reading this post is telepathic and "the following doesn't work" isn't much to go on. Why doesn't it work? Does it not compile? Do you get an error/exception at run time? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Sorry. I guess I just assumed that there would be at least a few people that were telepathic ;-). 

It doesn't show anything.

Comment: can whoever down-voted me tell me why, I'll try to improve the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Posts class/view model can look like the following:

```
    public class PostViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUserViewModel PostOwner { get; set; }

        public List<ApplicationUserViewModel> PostContributors { get; set; }

    }
```

And Your ApplicationUserViewModel can look like the below:

```
    public class ApplicationUserViewModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public virtual List<dtoPost> Posts { get; set; }

    }
```

Adding a dto so you would not have a circular reference to the View Model:

```
    public class dtoPost
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUserViewModel PostOwner { get; set; }

        public List<ApplicationUserViewModel> PostContributors { get; set; }

    }
```

You can access the Email of the Post owner like this in the  index view of Post with a reference to the PostViewModel:

```
@model WordClues.ViewModels.PostViewModel

    <div>
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PostOwner.Email)
    </div>
```

You have to write the appropriate Controller Method in your code. BTW it is asp.net MVC.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking something along these lines, but this makes more sense; so I assume I would have to construct a list of PostViewModels and return that in the index method of the PostsController?

Comment: @dhouse42 I edited my original post. If you are designed your app to write to the DB then the dto would be better choice rather than a reference back to the View Model. I realized over-extended the scope of your question. However it helps to review your design and than put those view models in place so they achieve your objectives. Also I assumed that when you said it is not working that they were not being displayed.

Comment: @dhouse42 Adding another post due to max length : Answer to your question depends on what you are trying to achieve in your view? Is it a summary of posts with links to the details? Then yes. Also you may want to consider if your view is post-centric or Application-user centric. Also if you think it answers your question, please consider upvoting :)

Comment: You answered my question, thanks! I upvoted but it doesn't show apparently until I have a higher reputation (15)

Comment: @dhouse42 Thank you! Glad to hear that it was useful!